# delete previous line in postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

[image]

I'm doing a face recognition project and my output from this project is a PostgreSQL database that is stored every time a person is identified by the name of the person in the database. I use the python programming language and psycopg2 module for make this output. What I need is until the new one is detected, then the previous line in the database is deleted. Thank you in advance.

---

thank you for your support
[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSAhA.png)

I have a table that stores the images path with a limited number id
I want to show appropriate image when my system detected for example a happy man,
For this purpose, I want to join the two tables(images table and face classification table), but my table introduces the IDs serially and I can not join them.

Comment: What do you mean with previous row? The is no order in SQL tables.

Comment: i mean is previous person detected,when i detected new person then previous row deleted and add new person in my table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order of the ids correlates to the order of insertion: You can fetch the `id` in descending order of the persons lower than the last added, and taking the first one.

```
SELECT id FROM person WHERE id < $1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

where `$1` stands for the `id` of the row inserted. With the fetched `id` you can delete the row.

A better way would be storing the times as timestamps instead of texts

Comment: "A better way would be storing the times as timestamps instead of texts" Or at least use ISO 8601 date format which sorts correctly as text.

Comment: @rofls: No, I don't agree with you. Dates an times should also be saved as date or timestamp. This makes a lot easier, e.g. handling timezones, converting for representation, calculations etc.